# Eclipse shortcut on fedora19 from command line

Tags: fedora

I would like to run eclipse directly from "enter a command" line.
I tried to do something and caused me some bugs now i am having gnome errors.
And before i was having eclipse directory now i don't have anything when i  type "eclipse" to
alt+f2 command line.

Also i am looking to fix the gnome now , i am using eclipse kepler 4.3
[This is the link that i tried to implement](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/linux-fedora-15-install-eclipse-sdk-3-7-indigo) and i failed doing it.
I am really in need of help now.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found my error ,

instead of my own directory , i tried to put nano /usr/bin/eclipse

so now the solution is :

```
touch /usr/bin/eclipse
chmod 755 /usr/bin/eclipse

## Open eclipse file with your favourite editor ##
nano -w /usr/bin/eclipse

## Paste following content to file ##
!/bin/sh
export ECLIPSE_HOME="/opt/eclipse"

$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
```